# Align center view in relativealyout to another view outside of the relativelayout

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

I need to make the RelativeLayout and its two Views center with the TextView "title". This works when both the views in the RelativeLayout are present. However, sometimes (based on some condition) i don't need to show the "arrow" ImageView. In this case the textView "phone_name" inside the RelativeLayout is not center with the TextView "title". It's a bit off to the left. How can I make this both cases work?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/mineral"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:maxLines="1"
            app:customTypeface="@string/font_sharp_sans_bold"
            tools:text="Hello Joel"/>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/select_phone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_selector">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/phone_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:textColor="@color/charcoal"
                android:maxLines="1"
                app:customTypeface="@string/font_sharp_sans_semi_bold"
                tools:text="Samsung Galaxy"/>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/arrow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_drop_down"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:rotation="180"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused, from what I understood you need **both** your views inside `RelativeLayout` to be centered, but in you code `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` this line makes the ImageView to always be aligned to the right side of the layout 

In that case I suggest you change it to `android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/phone_name"` (for API below 17 you need to add `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/phone_name"` too) and add `android:gravity="center"` to the `RelativeLayout`

Ignore if i misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

you can try below solution - it makes phone_name center when ImageView visibility gone -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/mineral"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:maxLines="1"
            app:customTypeface="@string/font_sharp_sans_bold"
            tools:text="Hello Joel"/>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/select_phone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_selector">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/phone_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:textColor="@color/charcoal"
                android:maxLines="1"
                app:customTypeface="@string/font_sharp_sans_semi_bold"
                tools:text="Samsung Galaxy"/>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/arrow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_drop_down"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:rotation="180"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Adding "android:gravity="center"" does not change anything